# Python Expression that returns a value if condition is met but otherwise continues a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, ternary, f-string, pep

This is going to sound like a dumb and horrible idea and that's probably because it is.
Is there a way in Python (preferably a one-liner) to create an **expression** that resolves to a value if a condition is met but if the condition is not met it will instead execute a statement (such as `continue` or a method call)?

An example use case below (although this code doesn't actually work):

```
def print_name_if_even(n):
    print(f"{ name if n % 2 == 0 else print("Uneven!") }")
```

I know this probably is a bad idea but I'm doing a challenge to cram a function definition in as few lines as possible so I want to avoid muli-line conditional statements.

Comment: The challenge you are in is called code golf, be sure to check out the page with tips for golfing in python: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python

Comment: Wrap "Uneven" with single quotes 'Uneven' and remove  the nested print
`print(f"{ name if n % 2 == 0 else 'Uneven!' }")`

Comment: @lazos Sorry I gave a bad example using the print method. My question is more referring to another case where I wanted to run the `continue` method if the condition was false.

Comment: continue isn't a method.

Comment: you're not iterating over anything - how would continue even be used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
def f():
    # <your statement>
    return 'yourstatement'

print ([f(), 'Even!'][False])
```

Replace `False`  by any condition that evaluates to True(=1) or False(=0).
(This is fun). For example:

```
def f():
    # <your statement>
    return 'yourstatement'
n=2
print ([f(), 'Even!'][n%2 == 0])
```